# Поставить ограничения на таблицы в MS Access

Tags: sql, access, office

Подскажите, можно ли без создания форм, ввести какие-то ограничения на таблицы?

К примеру, что бы пользователи могли просматривать таблицу, но не могли редактировать.

Можно ли поставить ограничение на перечень колонок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Система безопасности MS Access реализована на рудиментарном уровне и обходится очень просто. Раньше (Access 97-2003) пользовался следующим хаком:

- Таблицы, которые нужно скрыть, выносятся в отдельную БД;
- В этой отдельной БД, в диалоге "Параметры запуска" сбрасываются галки **показать окно базы данных** и **включить стандартные комбинации клавиш**;
- БД кладется на сетевой диск;
- В основной БД делаются запросы к скрытым таблицам с нужными фильтрами. Запросы пишутся так, чтобы возвращать не изменяемые наборы данных.

**Не забывать про резервные копии**

Answer (score 1):

Ограничение на таблицы можно поставить через файл рабочих групп.
Раньше он имел расширение mdw. Соответственно, в access есть GUI для редактирования этого файла.